# Normal ideal over a singular cardinal

Tags: set-theory, filters

Let $\kappa$ a singular cardinal. I want to show that there is no normal ideal $I$ which contains all of bounded subsets of $\kappa$.

If that ideal exists, I can to show that $club(\kappa)\subseteq I^*$ which is a $cf(\kappa)$-complete filter (Here, $I^*$ denotes the dual filter of $I$), but I don't know if this fact is useful.

Can someone give a hint to solve my problem? (please, don't give me the answer).

Thanks

Comment: In the case of a singular cardinal does the definition of *normal* require the filter to be closed under diagonal intersections of families of cardinality $\kappa$ or $\mathrm{cof}(\kappa)$?

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti I'm follow the Jech's book set theory (chapter 8). There, he doesn's say nothing about normal in the case of singular cardinals (At least, I didn't see its definition). I think that it must  be closed  under digonal intersection of leght $\kappa$, however, in the other case, I can also show that $club(\kappa)\subseteq I^*$ because every club set contains a club set with order-type $cf(\kappa)$.

Comment: As a hint, you may want to investigate what other implications this normality condition might have. E.g. is $I^*$ $\lambda$-complete for some good $\lambda$? Maybe $\lambda=\kappa$? If it were so, would it help? (I am writing this comment vaguely, since you mentioned you don't want the full answer.)